# I want to draw a route for directions which will have multiple turns

Tags: android

"I need to draw a transitioning line (like moving from point A to point B), a route line, i.e. line shouldn't appear suddenly, but it should be drawing from point to point like we see a loading line from left to right. I want to draw a route for directions which will have multiple turns."

I am drawing lines using onDraw, but they are appearing all of a sudden without animation, I am also moving an object along the line for an effect.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.d("tag1", "42222");
    for (AnimationThing thing : animationThingsList){
        Log.d("tag1", "47777");
        //!!! Only the path of the last thing will be drawn on screen
        canvas.drawPath(thing.animPath, thing.paint);



        if (thing.distance < thing.pathLength) {
            thing.pathMeasure.getPosTan(thing.distance, thing.pos, thing.tan);

            thing.matrix.reset();
            float degrees = (float) (Math.atan2(thing.tan[1], thing.tan[0]) * 180.0 / Math.PI);
            thing.matrix.postRotate(degrees, thing.bm_offsetX, thing.bm_offsetY);
            thing.matrix.postTranslate(thing.pos[0] - thing.bm_offsetX, thing.pos[1] - thing.bm_offsetY);

            canvas.drawBitmap(thing.bm, thing.matrix, null);

            thing.distance += thing.step;

        } else {
            thing.distance = 0;
        }
        break;

    }


    invalidate();
}
```

I need a line with a feeling being draw while the user views it.

Comment: Have you considered doing this in a map object?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to draw line on an image and not map. so, I didn't look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add Google map you can take advantage of [Google roads api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) and let them worry about drawing the route on the road, rather than you having to do the heavy load of calculating the optimized route on the map.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I have used the data offset transistions to draw the line,  it is simpler to execute